# Getting results back to the caller from worker threads

Tags: java, multithreading

There are some answers on SO but I'm looking for a solution using my code for clear understanding.

I've created worker threads using Executor, and after performing work, the workers are to return results back to the caller (main)

**Worker**

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {

    private final int num;

    public Worker(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting job: " + num);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("end job:" + num);

            String result = "result " + num; // how to pass all the results back to the caller

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Worker Test**

```
public class WorkerTest {

    private static List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new Worker(i);
            executorService.execute(worker);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        while(!executorService.isTerminated());
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://dzone.com/articles/basics-of-using-java-future-and-executor-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your complete code 
public class WorkerTest {
    private static List result = new ArrayList<>();

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Future[] futures = new Future[10];
    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Callable worker = new Worker(i);

        futures[i] = ex.submit(worker);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String resultString = (String) futures[i].get();
        System.out.println(resultString);
    }
    ex.shutdown();
    while (!ex.isTerminated());
}

}

class Worker implements Callable<String> {

private final int num;

public Worker(int num) {
    super();
    this.num = num;
}

@Override
public String call() throws Exception {
    String result = null;
    System.out.println("starting job " + num);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("end job " + num);
        result = "result" + num;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Or you can do this way if you want to store results in list.

```
public class ExecutorTest {
private static List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Callable worker = new Worker(i);

        Future<String> stringResult= ex.submit(worker);
        String output = stringResult.get();
        result.add(output);
        System.out.println(output);

    }
    ex.shutdown();
    while (!ex.isTerminated());
    System.out.println("All results received frmo executor service ");
    System.out.println(result);
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `Runnable` you should implement [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and then use a method returning a `Future`

```
public class Worker implements Callable<String> {
  @Override
  public String call() {
    return "123";
  }
}


ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
Future<?> f = es.submit(new Worker());
String result = f.get(); // 123
```

Comment: Can you please provide an answer using my code example, I can't wrap my head around it

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate, i'm getting it, can you modify it to have 10 submissions, and wait for all 10 to complete, that's where the whole picture will be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

> > I can't wrap my head around [Futures].

Maybe a brief glimpse behind the curtain would help

`Future` is an interface, but there is some standard library class, whose name we do not know, that `implements Future`.  Let's pretend it's called `FutureImpl`.

A `FutureImpl` instance has a `get()` method that is specified by the [`Future` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), and it has another method that we can't see, but let's call it `put(x)`.

When Karol Dowbecki's example code submits a task to the executor service, the executor service creates a new `FutureImpl` instance and does two things with it:

1. It gives a reference to the worker thread that is going to execute your task, and,
2. It returns a reference from the `es.submit(...)` call.

   ```
   Future<?> f = es.submit(...);
   ```

The worker thread will call the task function that you give it, and then it will take the returned value, and stash it in the `FutureImpl` object:

```
futureImpl.put(task.Call());
```

> Note! `f` and `futureImpl` are two different names for the same object. The only difference is, the worker thread knows that it is an instance of the `FutureImpl` class, but the main thread only knows that it is an instance of some class that `implements Future`.

Anyway, back to the main thread... It can do other stuff while the worker is doing its thing, and then eventually, the main thread can try to retrieve the value:

```
String result = f.get();
```

If the task has already completed, and the worker has already called `futureImpl.put(...)` before the main thread calls `f.get()` then `f.get()` will immediately return the value.  But, if the main thread calls `f.get()` first, then the `get()` call will *wait* until the worker thread completes the task and stashes the value.